# Google Chrome equivalent to Firefox microsummary bookmarks?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

Is there a Google Chrome equivalent to Firefox [microsummary](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Microsummaries) bookmarks?

(If there isn't one already I'm guessing it should be possible to automate turning them into Chrome extensions, although the summary would have to be in a popup from a Browser Action icon.)

**Update:** to be specific, I want something to replace my [Stackoverflow microsummaries](http://sam.haslers.info/firefox-microsummaries.html); I'm not talking about the RSS live titles bookmarks.

Comment: Given that Chrome 4 should natively support Greasemonkey, it shouldn't be to hard to create something like this

Comment: @Ivo Greasemonkey acts on a page, I want something in the chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new version of chrome, 4.0 supports Extensions. Try the [Feedly extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ndhinffkekpekljifjkkkkkhopnjodja), which is a glorified RSS reader, based off your Google reader feeds (not bookmarks, sorry). You can switch to the List view, which gives you one-line bookmarks with a summary, ie a micro summary.

It's quickly accessible from your toolbar, too.

Comment: It's microsummaries, not RSS live titles that I want to convert.

Comment: No there is no Chrome equivalent yet.

Comment: I did end up doing this in an extension. So this was the best solution. And writing chrome extensions was a lot easier (and more fun) than I was expecting.